# Как увеличить значение элемента при касании связанного с ним объекта?

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать квадрат, в нем находится 0. Задача - при нажатии на квадрат увеличить значение 0 на 1. Как это сделать?

Comment: С чем именно возникла сложность? Или вы хотите, чтобы просто кто-нибудь решил эту сверхсложную задачу вместо вас?

Comment: Я новичек в программировании в целом, и уже пытался решить эту задачу, но все-таки не получилось, поэтому обратился за помощью

Comment: Тогда покажите то, что уже сделали сами, а с проблемными местами сообщество постарается помочь.

Comment: let box = document.querySelector('.box'),
    num = document.querySelector('.num'),
    numValue = +(num);



box.addEventListener('click', function()  {
    numValue = parseInt(numValue) + 1;
});

Comment: Метод `querySelector()`  возвращает не текстовое содержимое элемента, а сам элемент (объект). Используйте свойство, например, [textContent](https://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties#textcontent-prosto-tekst). И последовательность должна быть следующей: после события клика на элементе, получить значение из элемента, увеличить его на единицу ([инкремент](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#inkrement-dekrement)) и записать обратно полученное значение (свойство `textContent`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("square").addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.innerHTML = parseInt(this.innerHTML) + 1
})
```

```css
#square{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
color: white;
background: red
}
```

```html
<div id="square">0</div>
```

Мы берем элемент "square" по id с помощью 
document.getElementById, потом "вешаем" на него [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) на клик. Как только происходит клик выполняется функция:

```
function() {
    this.innerHTML = parseInt(this.innerHTML) + 1
}
```

Которая берет [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) через this у объекта на котором висит eventListener через [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) и присваивает ему новое значение увеличенное на единицу.

Comment: Не совсем корректно, так как при каждом нажатии выводится новая единица, а должно происходить прибавление

Comment: Исправил, не оч понятно выражение увеличить с 0 на 1. Как будто 1 раз должно быть

Comment: Если не сложно, можете объяснить, как работает скрипт?

Comment: Обновил. Если не понятно что то, то в ВК меня можешь добавить я объясню - https://vk.com/dimabytes . Ну или где тебе удобно